# Elasticsearch char_filter not effecting search

Tags: elasticsearch, unicode

My understanding of how the char_filter works must be wrong. My goal here is to treat all apostrophes and quote like characters the same (in this case, remove them entirely) in elasticsearch. (Apparently there are like 5 apostrophe-like unicode characters... and my database has all versions :facepalm:)

Aside: This approach to the solution was inspired by [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filtering-for-apostrophes-and-single-quotes-confusion/12102/3)

So here is a toy problem that illustrates my issue.
I create an index with the char_filter, and then populate it with 3 documents:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "quote_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "quotes"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "quotes": {
          "mappings": [
            "\u0091=>",
            "\u0092=>",
            "\u2018=>",
            "\u2019=>"
          ],
          "type": "mapping"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "name": "The King’s men",
  "id": "1"
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "name": "Zoom LeBron the Soldier 7 'King's Pride'",
  "id": "2"
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "name": "Kings Kings Kings",
  "id": "3"
}
```

As you can see, each document contains some form of the word `Kings`. I then check that my analyzer is doing what I think it should be doing:

```
GET test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "quote_analyzer",
  "text": "King’s boat"
}
```

Which yields:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "Kings",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "boat",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

It appears that the apostrophe in `King’s` has been removed and the token is `Kings`. Great! So now I want to search for `King’s` and since the analyzer is removing the apostrophe I should get all three results. Or at LEAST I would get just `id:3` as the apostrophe was removed, and it only matches that `Kings Kings Kings` without the apostrophe. However, searching for:

```
GET test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "King’s boat"
    }
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  // collapsing ....
  "hits" : {
     // collapsing ....
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1e2x_38Bn0QWlup8OIvp",
        "_score" : 1.1220688,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "The King’s men",
          "id" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Similarly, searching `Kings boat` only retrieves `id:3`. And searching `King's boat` only retrieves `id:2`.

What am I missing? How do I accomplish the goal of treating all apostrophe characters the same?

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your `char_filter` to accommodate both quotes and apostrophe, like you already did for quotes.